# Commutative property of subtraction and addition of negatives

Tags: arithmetic

Why is it that subtraction is noncommutative but addition of a negative number is? Everything I can read says that subtraction can be view as adding a negative. However, when you view it in this way the noncommutative property of subtraction is broken. Therefore can they not be considered equivalent?

An example:
Subtracting two numbers
$$ 2-3= -1 $$
$$ 3-2 =1 $$
Viewing it as adding a negative
$$ 2+(-3)=-1 $$
$$ (-3)+2=-1 $$
Therefore upon viewing it as adding a negative one of the principal parts of subtraction is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To view subtraction as addition with negatives we must change the sign of the ***second*** number and *after* we do that we can rearrange the order.  But the number which sign is changed *must* be the ***second*** number and never the first.  If we change the order of subtraction it wouldn't be the second number that changes sign.  Once it *becomes* addition we can rearrange the numbers any way we want.  But we can't rearrange the numbers **before** it becomes addition.